# Remove comment lines from a file

Tags: python, list, comments, file-type

I'm making a file type to store information from my program. The file type can include lines starting with #, like:

```
# This is a comment.
```

As shown, the # in front of a line denotes a comment.
I've written a program in Python that can read these files:

```
fileData = []

file = open("Tutorial.rdsf", "r")

line = file.readline()

while line != "":
    fileData.append(line)
    line = file.readline()

for item in list(fileData):
   item.strip()

fileData = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), fileData))

print(fileData)
```

As you can see, it takes the file, adds every line as an item in a list, and strips the items of \n. So far, so good.

But often these files contain comments I've made, and such the program adds them to the list.

**Is there a way to delete all items in the list starting with #?**

Edit: To make things a bit clearer: Comments won't be like this:

```
Some code:
{Some Code}    #Foo
```

They'll be like this:

```
#Foo
Some code:
{Some Code}
```

Comment: Don't use a while loop, iterate over the file directly. Your `readline` while loop can be replaced by `fileData = file.readlines()` (plural) or `fileData = list(file)`.

Comment: Your `for` loop stripping the lines doesn't work at all because you never assign back the stripped lines. You didn't need to call `list()` no an object already a list.

Comment: See [What's perfect counterpart in Python for "while not eof"](//stackoverflow.com/q/15599639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process lines directly in a `for` loop:

```
with open("Tutorial.rdsf", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue  # skip comments
        line = line.strip()

        # do more things with this line
```

Only put them into a list if you need random access (e.g. you need to access lines at specific indices).

I used a `with` statement to manage the open file, when Python reaches the end of the `with` block the file is automatically closed for you.

Comment: Minor nitpick, if these are code files, then strip() will remove indentation (use rstrip instead).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I don't think we need to make quite that leap with this little context, and not all code depends on indentation.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: we don't even know if leading whitespace before the `#` matters. In my answer lines with whitespace before the `#` are not ignored, in yours they are. Both are valid approaches.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to check for leading `#` signs.

Change this:

```
while line != "":
    fileData.append(line)
    line = file.readline()
```

to this:

```
while line != "":
    if not line.startswith("#"):
        fileData.append(line)
    line = file.readline()
```

But your program is a bit complicated for what it does. Look in the documentation where it explains about `for line in file:`.

Comment: They should not be using a `while` loop **at all**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I did say that.